# Close Field Box with CSS - Gravity Forms

Tags: forms, gravity

I have a gravity form to solicit donations. Using conditional logic, when users select the "other" dollar amount to donate, a user-defined product field appears. I'd like a close box to appear on that field...ideally, in CSS. Any ideas on how to incorporate this into a gravity form?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this jquery function to your theme's functions.php file or your theme's page template. Change #field_1_3 with your selector's id.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery('#field_1_3').hide(); 
    });
</script>
```